# What is preventing my JavaScript from modifying the iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

There is an example [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/iframe-height/) where he inserts an iframe where the height of the iframe is changed to be the height of the inserted content. He explains the trick [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/how_to_adjust_an_iframe_elements_height_to_fit_its_content/).

However when I try and do it with my Bootstrap example, then something is preventing the JavaScript from modifying the iframe. `height` is never added to the iframe.

**Question**

Can someone see why `height` isn't added to the iframe, as it is done in the original example?

I am using this as iframe content

```
wget http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/iframe-height/iframe-content.html
```

and my html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      iframe {
         width:100%;
         margin:0 0 1em;
         border:0;
      }
      #external-frame {min-height:800px;}

      body {
         padding-top: 70px;
      }

      .container .jumbotron {
         background-color: #ffffff;
         padding-right: 0px;
         padding-left: 0px;
         height: 100%;
         margin:0 auto;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      window.onload = function () {
         setIframeHeight(document.getElementById('external-frame'));
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
    <iframe src="iframe-content.html" frameborder="0" id="external-frame"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Generally it's not allowed for code in one domain to mess with the contents of an `<iframe>` loaded from a different domain.

Comment: That would be the same-origin policy !

Comment: I don't see `setIframeHeight` defined anywhere.

Comment: Press F12 and switch over to the console, then try again. research the errors that appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels too obvious, but it really looks like you just didn't define `setIframeHeight` or include any script that defines it.
If you want to *call* a function, obviously you need to *have* that function.
That's the function, copied from the [page you linked to](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/how_to_adjust_an_iframe_elements_height_to_fit_its_content/):

```
function setIframeHeight(iframe) {
    if (iframe) {
        var iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.parentWindow;
        if (iframeWin.document.body) {
            iframe.height = iframeWin.document.documentElement.scrollHeight || iframeWin.document.body.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
};
```

Paste it in your `script` tag and you should be good to go.

Comment: Could the down-voter please explain what's wrong with my answer?